# Periodic work requests using Work Manager not repeat the work

Tags: android, android-workmanager, background-task

I am trying to send notifications every 20 minutes using work manager **and it sends only one time once I  open the app for the first time and then it will not send a notification again** What is the reason

**The build.gradle (app)**

```
def work_version = "2.3.4"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

**The worker class**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    Context context ;
    public MyWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.context = context ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        NotificationHelper.PrepareNotification(context);
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

**Build the Periodic work requests**

```
WorkRequest SendNotification = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class , 20 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag("Notification")
                .setInitialDelay(6 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build() ;
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(SendNotification) ;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your work manager specific code! Can you may be try to add a log statement or write to a file in your `doWork` to ensure work manager is called and works correctly? The problem might be in `NotificationHelper` code.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. It only runs the 1st time and it seems like it is not rescheduled. Then, if I open the app (after the 15 min - 20 in your case), it does the work I wanted. Also, by looking at the logs, I can see that the worker does not even start on this "second run", so it does not seem to be any problem regarding what is being done in the worker afterwards

Answer (score -3):

You used TimeUnit.SECONDS and set it to 6 seconds.
The minimum duration of the workManager is 15 minutes!

Comment: That is his initial delay, not repeating interval.